# Rails Stripe How To Post Request From Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http-post, stripe-payments

I'm trying to integrate Stripe Connect with my rails application. Reading the documentation found [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/getting-started), I direct my users to the Stripe connection endpoint and am successfully redirected back to my application receiving the 'code' params from Stripe. Next step is to make a post request to Stripe using this code param, an example they give on their website:

```
curl -X POST https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token \
 -d client_secret=sk_test_Bt0BtznEVxO2etFU0CZdx4nK \ * This is the secret key from my appication? *
 -d code=AUTHORIZATION_CODE \ * Assuming this where I enter the code param *
 -d grant_type=authorization_code * Leave this set to authorization_code? *
```

Which would in return swap the 'code' in return for an 'access_token'. My question is what is the best way of making this post request from my controller? Should I have the redirect from Stripe containing the 'code' param to an action in a controller that makes the post request? **Most importantly** What would the code for this post request look like in rails?

Should I then save the access token to the database for the specified user for future ref?

Any help / advise would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Lee

Comment: Wondering if you ever figured this out? I'm having a similar issue in the sense that I need a bit more hand-holding and understanding of basics than most people assume I have when starting out working with an API

Answer (score 0):

Try stripe gem https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby. And read this doc https://stripe.com/docs/api/ruby

Comment: Sorry not what I was looking for. I am already using the Stripe gem and the document you link to is for their API not Stripe Connect specifically.

Comment: @LeeRowbotham Sorry, i was inconsiderate. If you using Devise for auth you can try use this gem for Stripe Connection https://github.com/isaacsanders/omniauth-stripe-connect

Comment: @LeeRowbotham Or you can use https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty for sending custom requests